# Responsive nav sidebar with company logo and information

Tags: sidebar, bootstrap, nav

Currently, our team's browser app looks like this:

[image]

up to this point, we built our app to target desktop. However, because we're moving to Android, it is imperative that we can also effectively target mobile devices. Upon trying to emulate that, through the Developer Console, the screen looks like this: 
[image]

The nav side bar and the company info are both gone! Furthermore, if we place a menu button next to our company logo, it may create confusing UX, as the end-user could easily fat-finger the menu button and end up hitting our logo instead. What would you advise we do, with respect to this?

Comment: Why do you think *user* needs your company logo?

Comment: As of right now, our logo is a quick way back to the home page, similar to how the StackExchange logo on this (and every other!) question on here provides a link "back" to stackexchange.com

Comment: Heads up that you should sanitize that screenshot since I now know the real names of two of your colleagues/clients/etc.

Answer (score 1):

2 months ago I had similar problem, which now is implementing.

For now the solution I see:

Logo should be transformed into sygnet and place in left-top corner

1. Categorization & nesting list elements in several levels:
   [image]
2. Using dropdown list in menu (like Material Design)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

1. Leave your logo at top left corner and put your menu hamburger to the top right corner. You can put your user profile there also. I did exactly that in one project.
2. Let your logo *be* your menu. Since the user has nowhere to click on a toolbar, they will click on logo eventually. As this will work for them, they'll accustom to do that every time. The idea here is following: your mobile user probably needs menu much more than to go to Homepage Dashboard. You will have special item "Dashboard" in menu (and it looks like you already have it anyway).

Also let me note you have a lot of menu items on the sidebar. Maybe your users don't all of them, at least in mobile. Not all of them look interesting for me as a user (sorry for that).